# Are complex functions whose limit at infinity is zero bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $f(z) : X \to \mathbb{C}$ be an (analytic) complex function, $X$ is $\mathbb{C}$ except finite sets. If $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=0$, then $f$ is bounded?

This question originates from following proof ( Joseph Bak, Complex analysis, p.125 ) :

[image]
[image]

Why $A_n$ is bounded function? Can anyone help?

Comment: Célio has already explained how the proof works, but the answer to the question you asked is "no"; consider $f(z) = 1/z$ on $X = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm a bit confused. What additional conditions made a difference of results between objects $f(z)$ and $A_n(z)$? ~

Comment: The $A_n$ extend to entire functions.

Comment: Uhm.. O.K. Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A_n$ approaches $0$ when $z \to \infty$, there is $M>0$ such that $|A_n(z)| \le 1$ if $|z|>M$.

By the continuity of $A_n$, there is some $N>0$ such that $|A(z)|\le N$ on the compact disk centered on $0$ and with radius $M$.

Therefore,
$$|A(z)| \le\max\{1,N\}.$$

Comment: Wow, O.K. Thanks !